# Call EJB from JSF Project

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have two projects one is EJB and Other is JSF project. I want to call EJB from the JSF controller. I am able to deploy EJB on JBoss 7.1 server, but **not** able to call (deployed) Local Ejb from JSF Controller. The Code and Error is below

EJB Code is below that is deployed on JBoss 7.1 Server

```
    package com.store.ejb;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.LocalBinding;

import com.store.dao.OrderDAO;
import com.store.dao.OrderDAOInterface;
import com.store.entities.Order;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class OrderBean
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBinding (jndiBinding="StoreEJB/OrderBeanLocal")
public class OrderBean implements OrderBeanLocal {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public OrderBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void addOrder(float orderPrice, Date orderDate, int customerId,
            Hashtable<Integer, Integer> product) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        OrderDAOInterface orderDao = new OrderDAO();
        return orderDao.getOrderList();
    }

    @Override
    public void editOrder(Date orderDate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteOrder(int orderId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Below is the Console after Deployment of EJB

```
22:50:24,860 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
22:50:25,201 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
22:50:25,273 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
22:50:26,302 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
22:50:26,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
22:50:26,342 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
22:50:26,350 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
22:50:26,374 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
22:50:26,379 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
22:50:26,434 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
22:50:26,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
22:50:26,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
22:50:26,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
22:50:26,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
22:50:26,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
22:50:26,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
22:50:26,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
22:50:26,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
22:50:26,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
22:50:26,740 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
22:50:27,167 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
22:50:27,199 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015002: Deployment of 'StoreJSF.war' requested, but the deployment is not present
22:50:27,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found StoreEJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called StoreEJB.jar.dodeploy
22:50:27,422 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
22:50:27,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9998
22:50:27,441 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-7) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8089
22:50:27,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
22:50:27,651 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "StoreEJB.jar"
22:50:28,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JNDI bindings for session bean named OrderBean in deployment unit deployment "StoreEJB.jar" are as follows:

    java:global/StoreEJB/OrderBean!com.store.ejb.OrderBeanLocal
    java:app/StoreEJB/OrderBean!com.store.ejb.OrderBeanLocal
    java:module/OrderBean!com.store.ejb.OrderBeanLocal
    java:global/StoreEJB/OrderBean
    java:app/StoreEJB/OrderBean
    java:module/OrderBean

22:50:28,231 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
22:50:28,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 3717ms - Started 172 of 249 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
22:50:28,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "StoreEJB.jar"
```

Below is the code of JSF Controller - from where I am trying to access/call EJB

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OrderController {


private String orderId;
private Date orderDate;
private String orderPrice;
private String customerId;

//@EJB(name="java:global/StoreEJB/OrderBean")
private OrderBeanLocal bean;

private List<Order> allOrders;

public OrderController() throws NamingException{
    Context jndiContext = getInitialContext();
    bean = (OrderBeanLocal) jndiContext.lookup("java:global/StoreEJB/OrderBean");
}

public static Context getInitialContext( ) throws javax.naming.NamingException {
    return EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext();
}

    // getters setters
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.aislab.accesscontrol.core.ui-2</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>afterwork</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/orders.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**INFO:** EJB-project is added in the JSF_project->properties->JavaBuildPath->Projects.

So when I run JSF_project It give following Exceptions/errors

```
22:52:28,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found StoreJSF.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called StoreJSF.war.dodeploy
22:52:28,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "StoreJSF.war"
22:52:31,135 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
22:52:31,137 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
22:52:33,581 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."StoreJSF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."StoreJSF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "StoreJSF.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.store.controllers.OrderController with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.StoreJSF.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/store/ejb/OrderBeanLocal;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.store.ejb.OrderBeanLocal from [Module "deployment.StoreJSF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

22:52:33,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "StoreJSF.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"StoreJSF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"StoreJSF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"StoreJSF.war\""}}
22:52:33,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment StoreJSF.war in 55ms
22:52:33,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."StoreJSF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."StoreJSF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "StoreJSF.war"

22:52:33,668 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"StoreJSF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"StoreJSF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"StoreJSF.war\""}}}}
```

So JSF Controller could not find the (deployed) EJB, but it should find it. Please let me know if I am wrong any where.

**Using:** Eclipse, JBoss 7.1 Server, EJB 3 and JSF 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Don't do lookups manually, but use Injection to let the container give you an instance of what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mean `@EJB(mappedName="java:global/StoreEJB/OrderBean!com.store.ejb.OrderBean")

private OrderBean bean;` 
**OR**

`@EJB

private OrderBean bean;`

I tried both but didn't work i.e. same result.